# IAM allowing a user to access everything for ec2 on a region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm trying to allow one user to all actions on us-west-2, this is the policy I have.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["ec2:*"],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:837625274593:*"
    }
   ]
}
```

I got the account number from "OWNER" parameter on an instance, not sure if is it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1375943389569",
      "Action": "ec2:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:Region": "us-west-2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That should enable the user to have all access to ec2 in only the us-west-2 region

Comment: Mmm im trying with this but always give me this error: We encountered the follow errors while processing your request: Syntax errors in policy. If i remove the condition part it works...

Comment: this policy is not enough, since the user would not even see the instance on the list if you are using the console, therefore the user needs to have allowed ec2:DescribeInstances. Also, for reasons i don't understand, even after having ec2:* the user won't have access to start/stop/reboot/terminate the instances