# Restrict ListStacks Cloudformation in AWS based on Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to restrict users to see the list of stacks in cloudformation based on a region? or at least restrict them to delete a stack?

This should be achieved via IAM policy

UPDATE#1
I tried with this policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1375943389569",
      "Action": "cloudformation:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:Region": "us-west-2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I'm getting an error on the cloudformation page for us-west-2:

```
    Error
     Unable to list stacks: User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXX:user/dummy is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:ListStacks
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IAM allowing a user to access everything for ec2 on a region](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112784/iam-allowing-a-user-to-access-everything-for-ec2-on-a-region)

Comment: @tedder42 did you see that I'm asking for cloudformation not for EC2???

Comment: Yes. It's done the same way. I started to answer but it's simply copy/paste and changing the `Action`.

Comment: @tedder42 not working with a simple copy/paste and changing Action. This is the policy:
    
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1375943389569",
      "Action": "cloudformation:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:Region": "us-west-2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: does that fail? What error message do you get? Edit your question to include that.

Comment: @tedder42 question updated